# Webpage not rendering correctly on GitHub pages

Tags: node.js, express, github, ejs

[how it rendering on github page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnfPo.png)The content and layout of my webpage, which is hosted on GitHub Pages, are not rendering as expected. The webpage appears to have only my repository name .

[what it looks like when it runs locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfIcA.png) can someone please tell me what are the possible reasons
link to my github repo https://github.com/subhadarshini1954/Blog-project

Comment: Github pages (i.e github.io) supports only static html, however it looks like your project is built on NodeJS. Hence it is not loading I guess

Comment: "Thank you for the tip : Github pages (i.e github.io) supports only static html I wasn't aware of. I'll explore alternative hosting options. Any further advice would be appreciated. Thanks again!"

Answer (score 0):

Your current link to the stylesheet is using an absolute path, which means it starts with a slash (/). This works fine when you run your website locally, but it does not work on GitHub Pages, because your website is not hosted at the root of the domain, but at a subdirectory named after your repository. For example, in relation to your repo website url will be something like https://subhadarshini1954.github.io/Blog-project/, and your stylesheet URL will be https://subhadarshini1954.github.io/styles/layout.css, which does not exist. So where you call your stylesheets, remove the slash such that it looks as the following: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css">` - just removing that front slash.

Comment: "Thank you for the tip on the stylesheet link! I've made the adjustment, but the issue persists. It seems GitHub Pages doesn't support Node.js projects, a detail I wasn't aware of. I'll explore alternative hosting options. Any further advice would be appreciated. Thanks again!"